how to make implement google map addresses autocompletion inside a TextFormField in flutter?
i have to implement google map on my application.
What i did so far is to implement a simple example like this :
      @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
        //_handlePressButton();
      }
    });

  }

    Future<void> _getPolyline(LatLng destination) async {
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleApiKey,
      PointLatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
      PointLatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude),
    );

    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      polylineCoordinates.clear();
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

      Future<Prediction?> _handlePressButton() async {
    Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
        context: context,
        apiKey: googleApiKey,
        mode: Mode.overlay,
        types: [],
        strictbounds: false,
        //components: [places.Component(places.Component.country, "us")],
        components: [],
    );

    return p;
  }

  Future<void> displayPrediction(
      Prediction? p, ScaffoldMessengerState scaffold) async {
    if (p != null) {
      GoogleMapsPlaces placesInstance =
          GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: googleApiKey);
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await placesInstance.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId!);
      final lat = detail.result.geometry!.location.lat;
      final lng = detail.result.geometry!.location.lng;
      destination = LatLng(lat, lng);

      mapController
          ?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(destination!, 14.0));
      _getPolyline(destination!);
    }
  }

currentLocation == null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            :
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (controller) {
            mapController = controller;
          },
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
                currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!),
            zoom: 14.0,
          ),
          markers: {
            Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId('currentLocation'),
                position: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                    currentLocation!.longitude!)),
            if (destination != null)
              Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId('destination'),
                  position: destination!),
          },
          polylines: {
            Polyline(
              polylineId: PolylineId('route'),
              points: polylineCoordinates,
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 6,
            ),
          },
        ),

it works fine, i can make :

addresses autocompletion
get my position and the destination
Trace a line between start and destination on the map

Now, the problem is that the TextformFields in which i put start and destination are given by default by the google map plugin and i would like to write starts and destinations inside  TextFormFields which i can customize appearance and style.
For that, i tried to use this package
but i got errors when appending the addresses, i can customize a TextFormField and implement maps autocompletion feature. But i cannot trace the line, i got this error (The API key provided is invalid).
So what is the best way to implement google maps with stylish TextFormField and with autocompletion, polyLine features ?

Would it be possible for you provide us with a sample app?
